# How can convert YYYY-MM-DD hh mm ss into MonthName, date, year | Hour:Minuts (am/pm) in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have date string `(2013-03-10 19:43:55)` and want to convert it in this format `(Mar 10, 2013 | 7:43 pm)` using JavaScript or jQuery. How can I do this ??

Comment: Just use Date object methods after you construct an object with `new Date('2013-03-10 19:43:55')`, there are so many examples..

Comment: Hi! I just wanted to let you know StackOverflow contains a _search_ feature (top left). If you look for [javascript] [jquery] format date you'll find what you seek!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending @arun-p-johny solution for a cross-browser compatible solution

```
function converter(s) {

  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  s =  s.replace(/-/g, '/');
  var d = new Date(s);

  var hour = d.getHours();

  return d.getFullYear() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' | ' + (hour % 12) + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ' ' + (hour > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am');
}

console.log(converter('2013-03-10 19:43:55'));
```

Reference: http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html

Comment: Be aware that this would be parsed as local time. You should include timezone information in the datestring if necessary

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
function converter(string) {
    var d = new Date(string);
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    var hour = d.getHours();

    return d.getFullYear() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' | ' + (hour % 12) + ' ' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + (hour > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am');
}

alert(converter('2013-03-10 19:43:55'))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZqCAr/3/)

Update:

```
RegEx based solution for cross browser compatibility
function converter(string) {
    var d = string.split(/[-:\s]/);
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    var hour = parseInt(d[3], 10);

    return d[0] + ' ' + months[parseInt(d[1], 10) - 1] + ' ' + d[2] + ' | ' + (hour % 12) + ' ' + d[4] + ':' + (hour > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am');
}

alert(converter('2013-03-10 19:43:55'))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZqCAr/5/)

Comment: in `chrome` is ok but on `firefox` its display `NaN undefined NaN | NaN:NaN am`

Comment: @Kashif solution working fine for me. 
just want to let you know 3rd month is March not April.

Comment: @Furqan a mistake in finding the month index

Answer (score 0):

Kashif's answer seems to be working +1, however, there is a small glitch.

If the minutes to be displayed are less than 10 then the according to his function instead of displaying "6:08 PM" it displays "6:8 PM". This can be solved by adding,

```
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
if(minutes<10){
    minutes = "0"+minutes;
}
```

Complete working function will be as follows,

```
function dateConverter(s) {

 var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
 s =  s.replace(/-/g, '/');
 var d = new Date(s);
 var hour = d.getHours();
 var minutes = d.getMinutes();

  //to display the minutes less than 10 with 0 as the suffix
  if(minutes<10){
    minutes = "0"+minutes;
  }
  return months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' , ' + d.getFullYear() + ' | ' + (hour % 12) + ':' + minutes + ' ' + (hour > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am');
}
```